# Getting different height and width in different browser using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

This is the code for getting the Dimension.

Dimension countrypickerDim = countryelement.getSize();

Results

IE 
Height =24
Width =94

Firefox and Chrome

Height=24
Width =96

i talked with developers and they are saying that they are using the Google Fonts so results will be deffer on different browser.

Please let me know how to deal with that.

Comment: I have a same code that check for the Height and weight so my test case is passing on Firefox and falling on chrome.How i can get same height and width on diffrent browser

Comment: If its the desired output then you should update the test. Also test are not supposed to update any look/functionlaity

Comment: Thanks Karna for the quick reply but if i updated my test case then i need to check for 2 different output as per browser. Somehow we can handle that through selenium

Answer (score 0):

Update your test accordingly, it's the "desired" behavior, IE is hell, nothing you can do with that.

The simplest method: switch-case for different browsers that assert the dimension according to the browser you working on.